# Create or append to array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
foo ||= []
foo << :element
```

Feels a little clunky. Is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: This **is** the idiomatic way. You can one-line it as `(foo ||= []) << :element`, but I find it uglier.

Comment: IMO the proper way is to have initial values. If you have ||= and << for the same variable within the same method, you IMO have a code-smell and did something wrong already. Asking how to do ||= << nicely is just doing cosmetics instead of fixing the real problem.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

```
(foo ||= []) << :element
```

But meh. Is it really so onerous to keep it readable?

Comment: +1 for "Is it really so onerous to keep it readable?" Readability is king.

Comment: If `foo` itself is a more complex expression, like a (nested) hash in which you look up values, this is a nice way to avoid looking up the values multiple times or spending another variable for the looked up array value.

Answer (score 67):

You can always use the push method on any array too. I like it better.

```
(a ||= []).push(:element)
```

Answer (score 12):

You also could benefit from the [Kernel#Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array), like:

```
# foo = nil
foo = Array(foo).push(:element)
# => [:element]
```

which has the benefit of flattening a potential Array, like:

```
# foo = [1]
foo = Array(foo).push(:element)
# => [1, :element]
```

Comment: I'm not sure it will always be guaranteed in Ruby that `foo = foo` sets `foo` to `nil` when `foo` is undefined. Also, `Kernel#Array` doesn't flatten `foo`. It just returns `foo` if it's an Array.

Answer (score 2):

Also a little more verbose for readability and without a condition:

```
foo = Array(foo) << :element
```